# When i run migrate command. AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

When i run the following command
python manage.py makemigrations
I am using Django version 3.0.3
and python 3.8
I am learning django from documentation but it could not run makemigrations comman

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load        
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked        
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\sergio\Documents\Django-Project\2. AdvanceView\mysite\polls\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\sergio\Documents\Django-Project\2. AdvanceView\mysite\polls\models.py", line 9, in Question
    question_text = models.Model(max_length=200)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 408, in __init__
    opts = self._meta
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: `question_text = models.Model(max_length=200)` change it to `question_text = models. CharField(max_length=200)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `question_text` should probably be a `CharField`, not a `Model` object:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # CharField instead of Model ↓
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ⋮
```